# Terminating a program using carriage return in C

Tags: c

Quesion: Write a C program that will accept a line of text. Store it in an array & then write it out backwards. Allow the length of line to be unspecified terminated by carriage return but assume it will not exceed 80 characters
My Solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("\nEnter a sentence:\n");
    char sent[80]; // creates an array of length 80
    int i = 0;
    while((sent[i] = getchar()) != '\n')
    {
        i++;
    }
    sent[i] = '\0';   
    printf("The Reversed sentence is : ");
    for(i=i-1; i>=0; i--)
    {
        printf("%c", sent[i]);   
    }
    getchar();
    scanf("%c", &sent[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

Is my code correct?
(I was wondering about carriage return part)

Comment: I used to know that compilers were meant for this purpose.

Comment: _Is my code correct?_ I dont know. Did you test it?

Comment: Sorry, I am new to this site.

Comment: The code is working but I am not sure about carriage return part

Comment: _Sorry, I am new to this site_  That's fine.  Typically, questions should follow ***[the guidelines here](http://stackoverflow.com/help)***.

Comment: What is the fault with the output *`The Reversed sentence is : eerht owt eno`* ? Please explain, yours truly.

Comment: The output was fine. I was curious about carriage return part. I learnt that in Windows, Enter gets terminated by \r\n. But that was not working.

Answer (score 2):

What if you enter exactly 80 characters??? You will end up putting '\0' at sent[81], which is very bad...

sent[80] will be the '\n' and sent[81] the '\0'

Also I am not sure why you do

```
getchar();
scanf("%c",&sent[i]);
```

at the end of your function. i at this point is -1.

Comment: Sorry that code was unnecessary. What I learnt online was in Windows, enter gets terminated using \r\n. But the code was not working for (sent[i] = getchar()) != '\r\n')

Comment: I didn't test on windows...  However in any case you are definitely writing the '\0' outside the limit of your buffer if the user type 80 char (including or not including the line feed)